# Can't reset Ctrl-; or Ctrl-. in emacs

Tags: key-bindings

I am using GUI emacs 28.1 on ubuntu 22.04. Emacs won't let me reset the key C-;

I want to use:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-;") 'evil-normal-state)
```

Resetting the key C-. won't work either. The key C-; or C-. make a little popup with the letter "e" appear (see image below). It started to happen out of the blue, and I have no idea what it is.

Does anyone know how to stop that "e" to appear and reset C-; and C-. in emacs?

[image]

Comment: I suspect this key isn't getting to emacs. Are you in a linux desktop environment by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: My wild guess is that you're triggering the compose key. Check the settings of your desktop environment, which seems to be GNOME.

Comment: I thought so too, but I don't understand where the `e` is coming from: it seems unlikely that it's defined to be `Compose e` - but you never know...

Comment: It is the user-hostile GNOME emoji composition key: check the 'IBus' settings.

Comment: @FranBurstall, that is it. $ibus-setup -> Emoji -> "Emoji annotation" are the steps to turn it off. Thank you.

Comment: It’s not user–hostile if you want to be able to type emoji characters.

Comment: @db48x: the user-hostility is the undiscoverable nature of the bindings.  It took me a day to discover that that these bindings were set by `ibus`.

Comment: @FranBurstall how did you end up discovering that?  I'm curious b/c I was at a loss after checking the settings/xev. Is there a tool that does that sort of thing, like `describe-key` in emacs?

Comment: @Rorschach I know of no tool (the outside world is way less comfortable than emacs!): I simply searched SX and the rest of the net and poked around until I found what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you disable `C-;` and `C-.` in `GNOME Desktop`, those keys  will become available for `Emacs` to use.

#### Use `GNOME` to permanently disable `C-;` and `C-.` in `ibus-setup`

```
$ ibus-setup
```

[image: ibus setup]

[image: ibus emoji hotkey]

#### Use `gsettings` (preferably in a `M-x eshell` buffer) to narrow down the `GNOME` component of interest

```
~$ gsettings list-recursively  | grep '<Control>'

org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey ['<Control>period', '<Control>semicolon']
org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji unicode-hotkey ['<Control><Shift>u']
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings close-tab '<Control><Shift>w'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings close-window '<Control><Shift>q'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings copy '<Control><Shift>c'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings find '<Control><Shift>F'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings find-clear '<Control><Shift>J'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings find-next '<Control><Shift>G'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings find-previous '<Control><Shift>H'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings move-tab-left '<Control><Shift>Page_Up'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings move-tab-right '<Control><Shift>Page_Down'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings new-tab '<Control><Shift>t'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings new-window '<Control><Shift>n'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings next-tab '<Control>Page_Down'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings paste '<Control><Shift>v'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings prev-tab '<Control>Page_Up'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings zoom-in '<Control>plus'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings zoom-normal '<Control>0'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings zoom-out '<Control>minus'
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-panels ['<Control><Alt>Escape']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-panels-backward ['<Shift><Control><Alt>Escape']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down ['<Control><Shift><Alt>Down']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-left ['<Super><Shift>Page_Up', '<Super><Shift><Alt>Left', '<Control><Shift><Alt>Left']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-right ['<Super><Shift>Page_Down', '<Super><Shift><Alt>Right', '<Control><Shift><Alt>Right']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up ['<Control><Shift><Alt>Up']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-panels ['<Control><Alt>Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-panels-backward ['<Shift><Control><Alt>Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down ['<Control><Alt>Down']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left ['<Super>Page_Up', '<Super><Alt>Left', '<Control><Alt>Left']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right ['<Super>Page_Down', '<Super><Alt>Right', '<Control><Alt>Right']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up ['<Control><Alt>Up']
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys logout ['<Control><Alt>Delete']
```

```
~$ gsettings list-recursively  | grep '<Control>' | grep period

org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey ['<Control>period', '<Control>semicolon']
```

```
~$ ~$ gsettings list-recursively  | grep '<Control>' | grep semicolon

org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey ['<Control>period', '<Control>semicolon']
```

```
~$  gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey  "@as []"
```

Answer (score 1):

> It took me a day to discover that that these bindings were set by ibus.

There were multiple instances where I ran in to the same issue ...

For the solution to original question see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/71640/31220.

If you are interested in chasing down the thief that stole your `Emacs` keys in `GNOME`, read on ...

Down below

The `Elisp` code used to generate the Table using [gsettings.el --- GSettings (Gnome) helpers](https://github.com/wbolster/emacs-gsettings)

#### `Elisp` code to pry keybindings out of GNOME Settings

I am not a `gsettings` expert.  Nevertheless, the below `Emacs Lisp` code will take you very far ... If something is amiss, you can fix the below code and pass it on to others.

```
(require 'dash)
(require 'rx)
(require 'gsettings)
(with-current-buffer
    (generate-new-buffer "*Gsettings*")
  (pop-to-buffer (current-buffer))
  (org-mode)
  (let ((case-fold-search t))
    (save-excursion
      (->>
       "list-recursively"
       gsettings--run
       gsettings--split-lines
       (--map
    (cond
     ((string-match (rx-to-string
             '(and (group (one-or-more (not " ")))
                   (one-or-more " ")
                   (group (one-or-more (not " ")))
                   (one-or-more " ")
                   (group (one-or-more any))))
            it)
      (list (match-string 1 it)
        (match-string 2 it)
        (match-string 3 it)))
     (t (user-error "This shouldn't happen"))))
       (--select (and
          (let ((parsed (gvariant-parse (nth 2 it))))
            (not (and (consp parsed)
                  (eq (car parsed) 'parsec-error))))
          (or (string-match-p (rx-to-string
                       '(and "<"
                         (one-or-more any)
                         ">"))
                      (nth 2 it))
              (string-match-p (rx-to-string
                       '(and "Keybindings"))
                      (nth 0 it)))))
       (--map (let* ((bindings (gvariant-parse (nth 2 it))))
        (cond
         ((vectorp bindings)
          (let ((prefix it))
            (--map (append (list it) (butlast prefix)) bindings)))
         (t
          (list (append (list bindings) (butlast it)))))))
       (-flatten-n 1)
       (--map (cons (format "%s" (car it)) (cdr it)))
       (--tree-map (format "%s" it))
       (--map (format "| %s |\n" (mapconcat #'identity it " | ")))
       (apply #'insert))))
  (org-table-align)
  (sort-lines nil (point-min) (point-max))
  (save-excursion
    (insert (format "|%s|%s|%s|\n" "Key Binding" "Schema" "Key"))
    (insert (format "|-\n")))
  (org-table-align))
```